# Addressing Perl hashes nested in arrays

Tags: arrays, parsing, hash, key

Hi I am trying to parse an XML into a nested Array/hash list and am desperatly trying to get a list of keys from the Contact attributes which remains a hastable at the bottom. Here is my code:

```html
my $xml = <<'EOD' ;
<root>
<instance>
        <contact>
                <customerfid>101</customerfid>
                <firstname>Steve</firstname>
                <lastname>Jobs</lastname>
        </contact>
        <contact>
                <customerfid>102</customerfid>
                <firstname>mark</firstname>
                <lastname>blue</lastname>
        </contact>
</instance>
<instance>
        <contact>
                <customerfid>444</customerfid>
                <firstname>john</firstname>
                <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        </contact>
</instance>
</root>
EOD

my $data = XMLin( $xml, forcearray => ['instance', 'customer', 'contact']) ;
print Dumper( $data ) ;

foreach $n (@{$data->{'instance'}}){
foreach $m (@{$data->{$n}{'contact'}}){
foreach $key (keys %{$data->{$m}}){
print "key: $key \n";
}
}
}
```

When I run dumper this is my structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'instance' => [
                    {
                      'contact' => [
                                   {
                                     'firstname' => 'Steve',
                                     'customerfid' => '101',
                                     'lastname' => 'Jobs'
                                   },
                                   {
                                     'firstname' => 'mark',
                                     'customerfid' => '102',
                                     'lastname' => 'blue'
                                   }
                                 ]
                    },
                    {
                      'contact' => [
                                   {
                                     'firstname' => 'john',
                                     'customerfid' => '444',
                                     'lastname' => 'Doe'
                                   }
                                 ]
                    }
                  ]
    };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me.

Thank you in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Your XML has two instances, which is why the array is being created like that.  Change your XML to the following:

```
<root> 
  <instance>
     <contact>
             <customerfid>101</customerfid>
             <firstname>Steve</firstname>
             <lastname>Jobs</lastname>
     </contact>
     <contact>
             <customerfid>102</customerfid>
             <firstname>mark</firstname>
             <lastname>blue</lastname>
     </contact>
     <contact>
             <customerfid>444</customerfid>
             <firstname>john</firstname>
             <lastname>Doe</lastname>
     </contact> 
  </instance> 
</root>
```